# How to show a button or drop down list to only specific users in jacopo laravel authentication

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I want to show drop down list options to only admins. How can i do that in jacopo laravel authentification. How to use "can_see" option in views?
For example here is my list:

```
**<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/export_report">Export Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="/reports">General Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="/dailyreport">Daily Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="/monthlyreport">Monthly Report</a></li>
          </ul>**
```

i want to show "export report option only to admins so expecting something like that

```
 **<ul class="dropdown-menu">
              @if(can_see())
                <li><a href="/export_report">Export Report</a></li>
              @endif
                <li><a href="/reports">General Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="/dailyreport">Daily Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="/monthlyreport">Monthly Report</a></li>
          </ul>**
```